# Help me understanding a stacktrace

Tags: objective-c, crash, stack-trace, appstore-approval

I've built an iPhone app. It works fine on the simulator and on my 4 iOS devices that run several iOS4 versions, including an iPhone 4 running iOS 4.3.3
However when I submitted it to the appstore it got rejected because apparently it crashed upon launch on an iPhone 4 running iOS 4.3.3

They sent me the associated stacktrace. I symbolicated it but can't make sense out of it.
If you're a stacktrace genius and can give me a tip to point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful!

Thanks!

---

THE STACKTRACE:

```
Incident Identifier: AE062B8C-6EF3-4DE5-8862-C2B6E5B4ED69
CrashReporter Key:   0ecc752f46ea3a89537660d343cedea406a74833
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         myapp [5016]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/80837345-000A-4769-95AF-1F34D8C66809/myapp.app/myapp
Identifier:      myapp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-05-18 15:13:02.009 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.3 (8J2)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558fa1c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x356663b4 pthread_kill + 52
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3565ebf8 abort + 72
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x35628a64 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3449d06c _objc_terminate + 104
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x35626e36 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x35626e8a std::terminate() + 10
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x35626f5a __cxa_throw + 78
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3449bc84 objc_exception_throw + 64
9   Foundation                      0x34242924 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 648
10  CoreFoundation                  0x30957a72 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 6
11  CoreFoundation                  0x3095969c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 188
12  CoreFoundation                  0x3095a4e4 __CFRunLoopRun + 224
13  CoreFoundation                  0x308eaebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
14  CoreFoundation                  0x308eadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
15  GraphicsServices                0x30269418 GSEventRunModal + 108
16  GraphicsServices                0x302694c4 GSEventRun + 56
17  UIKit                           0x30a10d62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
18  UIKit                           0x30a0e800 UIApplicationMain + 664
19  myapp                           0x00002a02 main (main.m:14)
20  myapp                           0x000029cc 0x1000 + 6604

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x355903ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x356676d8 _pthread_wqthread + 592
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35590fbc kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x35261032 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 706
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3526203a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 86
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x352615ea _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 186
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566758a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x355903ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x356676d8 _pthread_wqthread + 592
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558dc00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558d758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x309582b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3095a562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x308eaebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x308eadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x35f5327e RunWebThread(void*) + 382
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566630a _pthread_start + 242
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x3f08048c    r5: 0x00000006      r6: 0x0019896c      r7: 0x2fdfe990
    r8: 0x00000001    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x3e5338c8
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdfe984      lr: 0x359b83bb      pc: 0x358e1a1c
  cpsr: 0x000f0010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x28fff +myapp armv7  <b22474dac7eb34438cb7fc2be88c910b> /var/mobile/Applications/80837345-000A-4769-95AF-1F34D8C66809/myapp.app/myapp
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe25fff  dyld armv7  <bb9bfc7d242331d29a79adf7ef7aaa18> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30357000 - 0x30380fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x30381000 - 0x303b8fff  Security armv7  <6599f42a910b3b31a0e1d98c883d61cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x303b9000 - 0x303bafff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <39bf0f48bd8539169a77f8f61cdcd4c9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x30406000 - 0x30416fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <66d9047da79a31daa887e6d84c42ecb2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x30417000 - 0x30417fff  Accelerate armv7  <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x30515000 - 0x305aafff  ImageIO armv7  <d520e3241d1130e8ac1375ee0f2c1095> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x305b7000 - 0x305c3fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <ff78a9636e933f0dbd222f8d26209788> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x30722000 - 0x30724fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <a2631ac302f4310dae8367939e16b7c2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x30725000 - 0x3083ffff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <bada0c2725bb31a483d5adf9aaf1f8df> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x30844000 - 0x3085afff  EAP8021X armv7  <9fefc0ada30435fbb3b51818c74f6cb8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x309e8000 - 0x309effff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <55f29184efcc3046bb833dd72a4487e1> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x309fc000 - 0x309fcfff  vecLib armv7  <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x30a39000 - 0x30a76fff  CoreText armv7  <fb6a72faec2330c4b2cd33c2e9c59588> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x30c34000 - 0x30d19fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <a8444f997111304c9571b3ff974b769c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x30d34000 - 0x310c1fff  UIKit armv7  <c271b78464d93cb7bf28c6e49df293ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x310e2000 - 0x311cffff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <f4146ce07e3031ea8a81fa5516fd77d0> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x311d0000 - 0x311d1fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <e8858a499d663e6a9e3c188521273cc1> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x311d2000 - 0x311dcfff  AccountSettings armv7  <d083fb384dc7311eb6766b9b2d2dd9c8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x311e2000 - 0x311ebfff  CoreVideo armv7  <ea847e6dba2d36b1826b255c73b39539> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x311ec000 - 0x3121ffff  StoreServices armv7  <d526715648f435c3aac4c42953e76d20> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x3123c000 - 0x3123efff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <d55f1553d14831a2a5435ae27ef75ef4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x3123f000 - 0x31290fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <8a41cc6a6d9332308bc415d27577fd24> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x312aa000 - 0x312b1fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x312b2000 - 0x312f5fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <f790c26852cb3cf298abe56bc9a3940b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x312f6000 - 0x312fbfff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <f5ccc8234aea3ebd9a88bd37f0fa23ae> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x31336000 - 0x31341fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <ac706bee36593dc683fd5a96a389d72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x314b2000 - 0x314b2fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x314b3000 - 0x314b4fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <ccc041df3de73eafb7a59e74cdb1702b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x314b5000 - 0x314d5fff  PrintKit armv7  <e5a01ca9083a36afacc08611a398e2ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x314e2000 - 0x31524fff  CoreAudio armv7  <c972fd5f8e89333ca680b9a33587f896> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x31af7000 - 0x31b2ffff  IOKit armv7  <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x31b70000 - 0x31bacfff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9d97699e44ee3651ba4ac37e5adec35b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x33772000 - 0x33777fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <8c35c090bc373cb181fc26b961b8dba5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x33778000 - 0x33781fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <03d98d5cf6383695aa7d8a88da52f410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x3388b000 - 0x3388efff  ApplePushService armv7  <015c68c15621348db9f6a012499170e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x3388f000 - 0x338d5fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <af7d1e770e5a3ffd8834a57fb5d40557> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x338d6000 - 0x338e2fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <c68262667ac8397a949ce4e92dfec7db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x339b7000 - 0x339b9fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <683f321680763e519d61541170ba2133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x339ba000 - 0x339bffff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <e57c2b9054b831d9a37119baaa4947cb> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x33aab000 - 0x33aaffff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a0772a32cd8b3b9194bb0c29807c1c5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x33ab2000 - 0x33abbfff  ITSync armv7  <ba8b48d061903e4096774344448776d0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x33be5000 - 0x33be9fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e1cbfe599c96369ca4bdb0dd99d3cd9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x33beb000 - 0x33c9cfff  WebKit armv7  <eb9a0d69c64b3127b2bffd71641add3b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x33c9d000 - 0x33caafff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0a1e2bb78d5138419ecad8ba0fe42fdd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x33d83000 - 0x33d89fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x34064000 - 0x34065fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <41a7b5e5d9983449ab33affed0f635ad> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x340d2000 - 0x340d5fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <43311c113a9d3182b7d007129819f029> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x340d6000 - 0x340ebfff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e92cfbb83f7b330db19181e797bb3f7b> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x342f2000 - 0x342f5fff  IOSurface armv7  <ad50e71624583d06b891344d832f9b08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x343f6000 - 0x34455fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <0b36b2272aa33a8c9aa22d99c89d7189> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x34505000 - 0x34624fff  Foundation armv7  <09ff368178c5321c9715b9c8d491d53f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x346f1000 - 0x347a0fff  QuartzCore armv7  <ef9632c9781f3101916b65e9faae1579> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x347e9000 - 0x348adfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <6b51e76fde9f381bb7b3bc5badbfee3a> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x34a93000 - 0x34ac6fff  AppSupport armv7  <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x34ac7000 - 0x34acefff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <ab9777b39e8e3026ad64dc90323cad7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x34acf000 - 0x34ad0fff  DataMigration armv7  <42e9e87a4e0735c3837e27d4f2adcf55> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x34ad1000 - 0x34bf2fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <65f6c8701b563542820a26b0dfc4f6a4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x34c33000 - 0x34f20fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <b855d60dac01310495453bddfd004f0d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x34f4c000 - 0x34f81fff  AddressBook armv7  <3f2071a77bc134cd82065eef90d4082f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x34f82000 - 0x35041fff  CFNetwork armv7  <b09e0d53de9f3bc8bde494780f3cdd4f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x35042000 - 0x3505bfff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x3517c000 - 0x352d0fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6619c8c13f8d328e923e797fa8d0df23> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x35371000 - 0x35372fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7b83cd757da73e6e826693c29296d3fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x35377000 - 0x35420fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3544b000 - 0x35450fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <c7cfe523e2d73521abc01587313ef730> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x3553e000 - 0x3555bfff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <48016be86e3f3cd9aeee1c6590e1ac6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x35595000 - 0x355a7fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <659ea9d5b13d3fefb37acff09016a69c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x355a8000 - 0x355acfff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d2f7fd2a352b3cd59c564be34b53cf80> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x355ad000 - 0x355bafff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9a0511ad5ebc3db898f1f49ed1a73d34> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x355eb000 - 0x3562afff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <33dcf9a403ae3fd5971d6030ada2fcab> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x3562b000 - 0x3562bfff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <42d8aa2a31843a6e8bfff745644a7ba5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x3562c000 - 0x356c9fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <e354aeb3d96e30338e90cc3638ffe81b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x356ca000 - 0x35739fff  ProofReader armv7  <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x3573a000 - 0x3578ffff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <0221caba81a235c5a896a835e2aac047> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x358cc000 - 0x358cffff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <fc834fd33a18341ea7506587ad895703> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x358d0000 - 0x358e7fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <a06ec84e53bf32098b63c0caebdb45b6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x35936000 - 0x35980fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <b2cac408951c3f3c9ba3cf563e54ce81> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x35981000 - 0x35983fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <94b6d6c5d9883175af26764567528127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x35985000 - 0x35a06fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <a7077267b6743ed3bbdd86d4380c75d9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x35a07000 - 0x35a3ffff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <ccea634795153164a681f0f311f4461d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x35e6b000 - 0x35f6ffff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <61a94142e2d23dafa2964190dd46e9e3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x35f70000 - 0x35f83fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <529ea6e3a87230ce9f6cf3285c22429c> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x35fcd000 - 0x35fecfff  Bom armv7  <b178e3efb4d733c694bd5a55e57a314f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x3629f000 - 0x368aafff  WebCore armv7  <07941e59d0a33f94802c16c76238fddf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x3697f000 - 0x369aefff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x369b8000 - 0x369c6fff  OpenGLES armv7  <5a76beaeaa013f0cbf16e5cb154598ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x369d9000 - 0x369defff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x36ae1000 - 0x36ae1fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <f47c01d627853b328e088b3fdd08e87d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
myapp
```

Comment: thanks dredful for the edit, I was formatting the code too but you were faster ;)

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this issue?  I have the same problem and can't find specific answers anywhere.

For me it happens only on iPad and only on iOS 4.3.3.

Comment: Actually I haven't :( But Apple eventually accepted my app. Since to be working fine so far, but there is probably a use case remaining that makes it crash. Good luck

Answer (score 4):

Generally SIGABRT (the signal that the operating system terminated your program with) means that there was a call to the abort() or terminate() function. This is the function used if there is an unhandled exception, so that's probably what your problem is. Also evidencing the case of an unhandled exception is the fact that the stack trace shows Thread 1 calling "objc_exception_throw."

I'm not exactly an iPhone development expert, so this might be wrong.

Comment: thanks Jack. I'm gonna look into that. Problem is I have no clue of what could be throwing that exception. If that can help, the main view of my app is a table view with contacts from the iPhone addressbook

Answer (score 0):

You need to [symbolicate](http://www.eigo.co.uk/Deciphering-iPhone-Crash-Logs.aspx) this crash log, which will convert `0x000029cc 0x1000 + 6604` from gibberish into lines of code, and allow you to see what part of your code is throwing an exception. In theory you can do this by dragging the crash log into XCode 4's Organizer window, but there are reports of a bug in XCode 4 that affects symbolication, so you may have to use one of [these](http://factotum.me/blog/2011/04/cant-symbolicate-xcode4-archive-builds/) [workarounds](http://www.goosoftware.co.uk/blog/the-symbolicator-helps-those-who-help-themselves/).

Comment: I belevied my crashlog was already symbolicated. Before I symbolicated it all of the lines looked like `0x000029cc 0x1000 + 6604`. Is it possible that it has only been partially symbolicated?

Comment: It looks like everything except "myapp" is symbolicated, which may be a symptom of the XCode 4 bug.